# How to install CDT plugin on Aptana Studio 3

Tags: eclipse, aptana, eclipse-cdt

Things tried:
Go to Install New Software -> Selected C/C++ development tools.
I get the following error

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: C/C++ Development Tools 8.0.0.201106081058 (org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 8.0.0.201106081058)
  Software currently installed: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.4.201108101506-10082011150838 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.4.201108101506-10082011150838)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Debug Core 3.7.0.v20110518 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.7.0.v20110518)
    Debug Core 3.6.0.v20100519 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.6.0.v20100519)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.4.201108101506-10082011150838 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.4.201108101506-10082011150838)
    To: org.eclipse.debug.core [3.6.0.v20100519]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ Development Tools Debugger UI 7.1.0.201106081058 (org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui 7.1.0.201106081058)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.debug.core [3.7.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ Development Tools 8.0.0.201106081058 (org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 8.0.0.201106081058)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.platform.feature.group [8.0.0.201106081058]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ Development Platform 8.0.0.201106081058 (org.eclipse.cdt.platform.feature.group 8.0.0.201106081058)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui [7.1.0.201106081058]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the plugin you are trying to install (C/C++ Development Tools) is intended for the version of Aptana/Eclipse you are using. The version of Aptana you are using seems to depend on Debug Core 3.6.0.v20100519 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.6.0.v20100519), while the version of the dev tools plugin you are installing depends on org.eclipse.debug.core [3.7.0,4.0.0), hence the conflict you are getting. Try to install an older version of the dev tools plugin that is intended for Eclipse Helios (3.6.*), and not Eclipse Indigo (3.7.*).

Good luck.

Comment: Correct. Aptana Studio 3 standalone is based on Eclipse 3.6, so you would need the 3.6 compatible version of CDT.  Or you could install both Studio 3 and CDT as plugins into a vanilla Eclipse 3.7 installation.

Comment: This is right. It now lets me start the actual installation but I still have the following error

Comment: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=AptanaProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Comparison method violates its general contract!
Comparison method violates its general contract!

Comment: -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true i tried putting that line into aptana ini file and started installation, but it waits forever trying to fetch a package, it just sits at 49% forever

Comment: the problem is that i have java 1.7 installed, and plugins need 1.6 to install properly

Answer (score 1):

use the following update site:

> http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/helios

these works for me.
but install only CDT main features.