# C syntax highlighting in Aptana

Tags: c, syntax-highlighting, aptana, sftp

I'm using Apatana to work on files hosted on C files located on a server I have a connection for. If I right click on a file and go to open with->text editor it sort of works and the source code is displayed in Apatana and but without any colour or syntax highlighting. How do I change the view for C development?

Comment: The text editor will not have syntax highlighting as it is just a text editor. You will want to open the editor appropriate to the code you are editing. AFAIK, Aptana does not natively include a C editor, you will need a plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458831/how-to-install-cdt-plugin-on-aptana-studio-3

Comment: I don't get those instructions. There is no "install" menu on mine.

Comment: Are you looking under `Help > Install New Software...`?

Comment: Ok thanks I installed the C/C++ editor but the default syntax colouring is unusable (the dark grey background and black text is nearly indistinguishable). How can I change the colours?

Comment: I don't have it, but at a guess: `Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Themes` or `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors` or `Window > Preferences > General > Appearance`